# Sed command yielding unwanted new lines

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

My source file has only 6 rows, but when I used sed command to apply text qualifiers it creating 2 rows for each input row.

Source File:

```
September 2022||2022|||13564|7JM9LF    |DANIEL, PAPERMAN
September 2022||2022|||48917|7CX04Q    |BROWN, RADY
September 2022||2022|||177456|75YBGL    |LAYYNE, MAXWELL
September 2022||2022|||5326|774YMX    |BROWN, WHITE
```

Target File:
[image]

Command used :

```
sed 's/\([^|]*\)/\"&\"/g' ./src_mod.txt > tgt.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: Most likely you need `< src_mod.txt dos2unix | sed 's/[^|]*/"&"/g' > tgt.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are trying to add quotes around all `|`-defined fields. The reason you are getting the extra newlines, is most likely because you have Windows-style line endings.

Just run `dos2unix src_mod.txt` or `sed -i 's/\r//' src_mod.txt`.

And here are some other ways of getting what you want, even though our original should also work:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^|]*)(\||$)/"\1"\2/g' file
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"13564"|"7JM9LF    "|"DANIEL, PAPERMAN"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"48917"|"7CX04Q    "|"BROWN, RADY"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"177456"|"75YBGL    "|"LAYYNE, MAXWELL"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"5326"|"774YMX    "|"BROWN, WHITE"
```

Or, if you cannot use `-E`:

```
sed  's/\([^|]*\)\(|\|$\)/"\1"\2/g' file
```

Or perl:

```
$ perl -F'\|' -lane 'print join("|", map{ qq/"$_"/} @F)' file
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"13564"|"7JM9LF    "|"DANIEL, PAPERMAN"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"48917"|"7CX04Q    "|"BROWN, RADY"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"177456"|"75YBGL    "|"LAYYNE, MAXWELL"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"5326"|"774YMX    "|"BROWN, WHITE"
```

Or perl:

```
$ perl -F'\|' -lane 'print "\"",join("\"|\"", @F), "\""' file
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"13564"|"7JM9LF    "|"DANIEL, PAPERMAN"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"48917"|"7CX04Q    "|"BROWN, RADY"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"177456"|"75YBGL    "|"LAYYNE, MAXWELL"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"5326"|"774YMX    "|"BROWN, WHITE"
```

Comment: I am getting following error, `sed: illegal option -- E` 
Is there any alternative for this ?

Comment: @Scales What Unix are you using?

Comment: @Scales see updated answer. But your command will also work, just remove the Windows line endings as explained in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: @terdon dos2unix is not supported. Meantime, your command without -E is not adding quotes `sed  's/\([^|]*\)\(|\|$\)/"\1"\2/g' file`

Comment: Above perl commands also not adding closing quote at very end position in all rows

Comment: @Scales `dos2unix` is one option, if you cannot install that (which are things you really should mention in your question so we know what to suggest), use the `sed` solution given right next to the dos2unix. And, again, all of these solutions require you to fix the file first so you don't have Windows style line endings.

Comment: `-i`, `\r` are GNUisms, not available in standard sed. `-E` is a BSDism, not standard yet.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas even `\r`? Hmm. So something like `sed 's/'$'\r''//' file > newfile && mv newfile file` would be needed?

Comment: Or just `<input tr -d '\r' | sed 's/[^|]*/"&"/g' > output`. AIX should have ksh93 where that `$'\r'` is from. Standard `tr` recognises `\r`. Or do everything in `perl` and avoid all portability issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely that your input file is not a Unix text file.  It may be a DOS text file.

A CSV-aware tool will ignore that your input is a DOS text file, allowing you to quote the fields appropriately natively.

The following uses `csvformat` to quote all the pipe-delimited fields.  The input has been converted to a DOS text file for this exercise:

```bash
$ csvformat -d '|' -D '|' -U1 file
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"13564"|"7JM9LF    "|"DANIEL, PAPERMAN"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"48917"|"7CX04Q    "|"BROWN, RADY"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"177456"|"75YBGL    "|"LAYYNE, MAXWELL"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"5326"|"774YMX    "|"BROWN, WHITE"
```

`csvformat` (part of [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) will, by default, only quote the fields that actually need quoting, as the last field in each record would need if you changed the field delimiter to the default comma:

```bash
$ csvformat -d '|' file
September 2022,,2022,,,13564,7JM9LF    ,"DANIEL, PAPERMAN"
September 2022,,2022,,,48917,7CX04Q    ,"BROWN, RADY"
September 2022,,2022,,,177456,75YBGL    ,"LAYYNE, MAXWELL"
September 2022,,2022,,,5326,774YMX    ,"BROWN, WHITE"
```

[Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is another CSV-aware tool:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs pipe -N --quote-all cat file
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"13564"|"7JM9LF    "|"DANIEL, PAPERMAN"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"48917"|"7CX04Q    "|"BROWN, RADY"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"177456"|"75YBGL    "|"LAYYNE, MAXWELL"
"September 2022"|""|"2022"|""|""|"5326"|"774YMX    "|"BROWN, WHITE"
```

This tool, too, only quotes what's needed by default.

```bash
$ mlr --csv --ifs pipe -N cat file
September 2022,,2022,,,13564,7JM9LF    ,"DANIEL, PAPERMAN"
September 2022,,2022,,,48917,7CX04Q    ,"BROWN, RADY"
September 2022,,2022,,,177456,75YBGL    ,"LAYYNE, MAXWELL"
September 2022,,2022,,,5326,774YMX    ,"BROWN, WHITE"
```

Use `clean-whitespace` instead of `cat` in the `mlr` command to remove flanking whitespace in fields, and remove `-N` if your input actually has headers.

Comment: I have limited resources, not allowed to use additional tools. Tried the same source source file by converting it to CSV but no luck

Comment: @Scales Could you mention what Unix you are using? That would make it easier for us to help you and would tell us more about the kind of tool restrictions you might be working with.

Comment: IBM,FW860.50 (SV860_160)

Comment: @Scales So, an AIX system?  Or are you running z/OS in Unix mode?

Comment: We are using AIX System

Answer (score 0):

`sed` doesn't do that, it doesn't add newline characters unless you tell it to.

Most likely here, your input file has MS-DOS CRLF line endings so from Unix point of view (where lines are LF-delimited), lines appear as ending in a CR character, so on output you get lines ending in `|"CR"` and for some reason the application you took that screenshot from renders CR as line delimiter as well.

Here, you'd want to convert those files to Unix format. `dos2unix` is the tool to do that, but if you don't have it, you can use `perl` both to remove those trailing CR characters and add quotes around every field:

```
perl -lpe 's/\r$//; $_ = join "|", map qq("$_"), split /\|/, $_, -1' <src_mod.txt >tgt.txt
```

With the caveat that empty lines are treated as a list of 0 fields as opposed to containing one empty field.

You could also remove *all* CR characters, not just the ones at the end of the lines with `tr` and do your substitution with `sed`:

```
<src_mod.txt tr -d '\r' | sed 's/[^|]*/"&"/g' >tgt.txt
```

Note that `"` should not be escaped in the replacement, and there's no need to use `\(...\)` capture groups, as `&` recalls the whole matched text (you'd use `\1` to recall what is matched by the capture group).